# Print unpacked set OR a single string if set is empty

Tags: python

Let's say I have

```py
set1 = {"apple", "orange", "pear"}
set2 = {"apple", "pear"}
set3 = {"banana"}
```

I want to print common elements between sets, like:

```py
print(set1 & set2)
# {'apple', 'pear'}
```

but I don't want the brackets, quotations, and commas - just the plain words. I can do:

```py
print(*(set1 & set2))
# apple pear
```

But if the computed set is empty, (e.g., `set1 & set3`), I want to print a string. Something like:

```py
print(*(set1 & set3) or "None")
# N o n e
```

However it seems like this understands the code as `*((set1 & set3) or "None")` and then unpacks the characters in "None" with a space in between. Is there a way to do this without that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that?

```
>>> print(" ".join(set1 & set2) or "None")
apple pear
>>> print(" ".join(set1 & set3) or "None")
None
```

Comment: Slight bug perhaps: For `set1 = set2 = {""}` you print `None`, even though the intersection isn't empty.

Comment: right, thanks @KellyBundy! @SaadHussain is that an issue?

Comment: Nope! I actually hadn't even thought of that but I think I prefer it this way with it printing `None`. The other answer is just as great though (although doesn't print `None` for two empty sets), wish I could choose both. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Put the `"None"` in a list, then when unpacked it'll be printed nicely

```
print(*(set1 & set3) or ["None"]) # note that inner parenthesis are useless
```